# 404 redirect and keep extensionless URL?

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-6, url-routing, http-status-code-404

I'm setting up custom 404 redirects (.htaccess is not an option as I'm on IIS6), is there a way to do this and still keep the 'fancy' url in the address bar?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such thing as "404 redirects". 4xx range means error.

In any case -- you can use [ISAPI_Rewrite 3](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) which will bring mod_rewrite support via .htaccess to your IIS6 server. It has Light version which is free.

Comment: I agree that a rewrite module of some kind would be better, but I'm working on the client's server and I can't install anything on it.

Comment: Well ... you may not, but you may ASK your client to install it to have such NICE functionality (if he really needs it). You give him few options and let him choose what he wants/can do. The problem is -- it's IIS 6 which has no much to offer in this area :/ . IIS 7 is a HUGE jump forward.